# Finding the equation to tangent line to a function given certain info - Multiple answers?

Tags: calculus, limits

[image: Image for problem]

The problem states: find the equation of the tangent line to the graph of continuous function $y = f(x)$ at $x=3$ given the following information.

$\lim_{x \to 3} {\dfrac{f(x)+7}{2x-6}}=8$      and      $f(3) = -7$

**How you are supposed to solve it**

$\lim_{x \to 3} {{\dfrac{1}{2}}\dfrac{f(x)+7}{x-3}}=8$ Take out 1/2

${\dfrac{1}{2}}\lim_{x \to 3} {\dfrac{f(x)+7}{x-3}}=8$ Take 1/2 out of limit

${\dfrac{1}{2}}\lim_{x \to 3} {\dfrac{f(x)-f(3)}{x-3}}=8$ As we know $f(3)=-7$, plug that in

${\dfrac{1}{2}}f'(3)=8$ By definition of limit, change $\lim_{x \to 3} {\dfrac{f(x)-f(3)}{x-3}}$ to $f'(3)$

$f'(3)=16$

Therefore, the tangent line at $f(3)=-7$ is $y+7={16}(x-3)$

**How I solved it**

As $\lim_{x \to 3} {\dfrac{f(x)+7}{2x-6}}=8$ and this is a continuous function where it exists (as $f(x)$ is continuous and $\dfrac{f(x)+7}{2x-6}$ is a rational function so $\lim_{x \to a}{\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}}=f(a)$)

I know that the ratio between the numerator and the denominator of $ {\dfrac{f(x)+7}{2x-6}}$ approaches 8 as $\lim_{x \to 3}$.

Therefore, at $x=3$ (we know the function $f(x)$ exists at $f(3)$ as stated in the directions)

$8(f(x)+7)=2x-6$

$8(y+7)=2x-6$ Directions stated $f(x)=y$

$8y+56=2x-6$ Factoring in the 8

$8dy=2dx$ Via implicit differentiation

$dy={\dfrac{1}{4}}dx$

${\dfrac{dy}{dx}}={\dfrac{1}{4}}$

Therefore, the tangent line at $f(3)=-7$ is

$y+7={\dfrac{1}{4}}(x-3)$

**Questions**

Could someone find an example where either the 'correct' answer or 'my answer' gives a correct answer?

Or perhaps explain where I went wrong?

Or is the problem itself fundamentally flawed?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I might be missing something but why do they have the slope is 16 and then changed it to 1/4?

Comment: You went from the ratio being $ \ 8 \ $ to writing $ \ 8·(f(x)+7) \ = \ 2x - 6 \ \ . $  The $ \ 8 \ $ should be on the _right_ side.  The slope _should_ be $ \ 16 \ $ and the "official" answer _also_ messed up on the final tangent line equation..

Comment: Ah, I see. I accidentally did $\frac{a}{b}=8$ so $8a=b$ instead of $a=8b$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they have given the : $f(x=3) = -7$

And they have also given the value of $$\lim_{x\to3}\frac{f(x)+7}{2x-6} = 8$$

Now, this must be the undermined form($\frac{0}{0}$) $\implies$ you can use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Now,

$$\begin{align*} \frac{f'(x =3)}{2} = 
8 \implies f'(x=3) = 8×2 = 16 
\end{align*}$$

Which is the slope of the tangent at $x=3$

Equation of tangent at point: $P=(3, -7)$ As they have already given $f(3) = -7$

$$\begin{align*} \frac{y+7}{x-3} = 16
\end{align*}$$